# CAxControl::FinalRelease

Tags: .net, browser, atl

What does `CAxControl::FinalRelease` mean and how do I suppress it? It's written to standard out when my Windows Form containing a Web Browser control closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a diagnostic that is generated with OutputDebugString().  Anything written with that API ends up in your Output window.  It is benign, you can ignore it.  Fixing it requires rebuilding whatever ActiveX control that's being used on the web page you display.  Getting the source for it ought to be difficult.

Comment: Quite annoying, however since I'm writing XML on stdout. Thank you for the informative response.